# Is there a short and elegant way to write an XPath 1.0 expression to get all HREF values containing at least one of many search values?

Tags: xpath

I was just wondering if there is a shorter way of writing an XPath query to find all HREF values containing at least one of many search values?

What I currently have is the following:

```
//a[contains(@href, 'value1') or contains(@href, 'value2')]
```

But it seems quite ugly, especially if I were to have more values.

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "needles". As in, needles in a haystack? Also: your title asks for "the correct" query, but your question seems to be about short and elegant (correct) queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in many cases you have to live with the "ugliness" or long-windedness of expressions if only XPath 1.0 is at your disposal. Elegance is something introduced with version 2.0, I'd daresay.

But there might be ways to improve your expression: Is there a *regularity* to the `href` attributes you'd like to find? For instance, if it is sufficient as a rule to say that the said `href` attribute values must start with "value", then the expression could be

```
//a[starts-with(@href,'value')]
```

I know that "value1" and "value2" are most probably not your actual attribute values but there might be something else that uniquely identifies the group of `a` elements you're after. Post your HTML input if this is something you want us to help you with.

---

Personally, I do not find your expression ugly. There is just one `or` operator and the expression is quite short and readable. I take

> if I were to have more values.

to mean that currently, there are only two attribute values you are interested in and that your question therefore is a theoretical one.

Answer (score 1):

In case you're using XPath 2 and would like to have exact matches instead of also matches only containing part of a search value, you can shorten with

```
//a[@href = ('value1', 'value2')]
```

For `contains()` this syntax wouldn't work as the second argument of `contains()` is only allowed to be 0 or 1 value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems I am not using XPath 2.0 :( This looks so much cleaner to look at.

Answer (score 1):

In XPath 2 you could also use

```
    //a[some $s in ('value1', 'value2') satisfies contains(@href, $s)]
```

or

```
    //a[matches(@href, "value1|value2")]
```